# Timber logs are not being shown in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, timber, android-studio-dolphin

Timber logs are not visible in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1

**Log Statements**

```
Timber.d("onCreateViewCalled using Timber")
Log.d("Login", "onCreateViewCalled using Log")
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Only the Log library logs are visible and not the Timber ones.

Comment: I have a problem with logs on emulator, but real device gives everything.

Comment: Yes I am having issue with emulator too. Seems like it is an issue with Android Studio and not Timber.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using your app module's `BuildConfig`

```kotlin
if (com.my.app.BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}
```

I was using the wrong one

```kotlin
if (org.koin.android.BuildConfig.DEBUG) { // <- NOT MY CONFIG
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by enabling `Use libusb backend`. Navigate to
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> then check `Use libusb backend`

[image]

Comment: Hey @fahrizal89 I can't see this option in Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1. Which version are you using ?

Comment: @oyeraghib I also using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Comment: I was using Android Studio Electric Eel also. but now using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

**Added this for future reference**

You have to **plant** a timber debug tree by initializing `Timber` in the `Application` Class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
    }
}
```

Add the **MyApplication** class to the `AndroidManifest.xml` like below:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">

    ...

</application>
```

Comment: Hi @Ad. Asaduzzaman, This was done in the project. The issue was due to Android Studio which has been fixed in new releases.

Comment: @oyeraghib, Thanks for the info. Actually, that was missing in my old project. Hence I added it here so that no one can ignore it.